# Change the URL structure using PHP

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want the URL structure like

```
 www.xyz.com/variable/value
```

I have one form with action URL is same page only and method GET.. When the user enter the value and submit the form i need the url like above in the url bar. I knew if usually using GET method the url like

```
 www.xyz.com?variable=value
```

only. But I don't want this.. Help me if anyone know the answer.

```
<?php
$get_variable = $_GET['variable'];
?>

<html>
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <input type="text" name="variable" />
    <input type="submit" value="save"> 
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: "echo" is spelled incorrectly and can you please explain you question better. Do you want a GET variable but without the ?blah= in the url

Comment: I believe you may be looking for url routing.  There are PHP frameworks that will do this for you.  Or, if you want to do it yourself, you can google for a tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, you're looking for something like:

```
<?php
$get_variable = $_POST['variable'];
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "/" . $get_variable;
?>

<html>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <input type="text" name="variable" />
    <input type="submit" value="save"> 
</form>
</html>
```

> Note: `action="<?php ehco $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"` this is definitely
>   not going to work. Watch out for `ehco`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite your urls using mod_rewrite, Try the following code  in your htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?$1=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

This will rewrite "example.com/variable/value" to "example.com/?variable=value.